# Searching function arguments in lambda

Tags: c#, function, lambda

Having a function:

```
Func<object, double> calculation = x => Row("1") + Row("2");
```

where Row is some function that extracts some data for example:

```
 public static double Row(string rowName)
    {
        return 100; // just an example irrelevant in this case
    }
```

i want to extract all arguments of Row function calls.  In this case

```
var parameters = Parse(calculation).ToList();
```

parameters would contain "1" and "2". I've started with:

```
private IEnumerable<string> Parse(Func<object, double> calculation)
    {

            // and I'm stuck here :) 
    }
```

What I would like to extract are values "1" and "2" and for the moment I'm stuck. Any ideas how to parse such function?

Comment: Please provide more details. What exactly is `Row` in scope? Do you mean to be `Row` a member of `x`?

Comment: Row is just some function


`public double Row(string rowName){ return 100; }`

Row is just an external function, quite posible static. It could be a member of x if it helps. For now it's just a concept :)

Comment: It's theoretically possible by inspecting IL, but you're better off using expression-trees here.

Comment: I was thinking about expression-tree but I'm stuck with that

Comment: Then your code seems to be syntactically correct; but it's not clear to me what the expected behaviour is. Following your example, `calculation` would return `200` for every argument.

Comment: updated the question, should be more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible to get the parameters passed to a method inside a delegate directly using .net. The closest you can get is `GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()` of reflection which returns a byte array. This is pretty useless by itself. Something to the effect of the following.

```
private IEnumerable<string> Parse(Func<object, double> calculation)
{
    var byteArr = calculation.GetInvocationList().First().Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();

    //returned null so that the method can build
    return null;
}
```

You can try with [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) and check if it can help you out in any way. I had tried it out once but not similar to your user case. The following are some of the post which might help you in understanding it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513319/mono-cecil-documentation-and-tutorials

http://www.bytecodeartist.net/2011/05/introduction-to-il-rewriting-with-cecil.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671259/Reweaving-IL-code-with-Mono-Cecil

All the best.

Comment: its not to comforting :/ i'll try to wrap it in a proxy function.